# Inspecting an instance of a COM / Interop class properly in VS.Net's debugger?

Tags: .net, com, interop, com-interop

Does anyone know if and how it's possible to see COM / Interop objects properly (in their correct type) in VisualStudio's debugger? All I get is the '*evil*' **System.__ComObject** value (even though it correctly identifies the type)?

E.g.:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: /me waits patiently for a good answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this isn't an answer, but check out these two screen shots.  This is from the same application, just at two different break points.  In both cases the COM objects are from the same COM/AX library.  I've no idea why in one case I see "System.__ComObject" and in the other the proper type.  However, in both cases, I'm seeing the appropriate object/interfaces properties.  What gives?  Why the difference?

The first one here shows it showing up a "System.__ComObject", however it's also showing me all of the properites of the object. Click to view the full sized image.

[image]

The second one completely hides the "System.__ComObject".  Click to view the full sized image.

[image]

Comment: Hey there,

maybe it depends on the way the variable is initialized/created? How has the first one come to life?

-J

Comment: I thought about that as well.  I was wondering if you get more information in the locals/watch windows if you instantiate it versus simply getting an object instance returned from a COM object. 

In the first picture, the 'unsplitShape' is returned from a COM object. In the second picutre 'scratchLayer' is an object that I've instantiated.

Are you running VS2003/2005/2008?  Service pack level?

Comment: I'm running VS2008 SP1 & yeah it seems related to the different ways to get an object: instantiation vs 'getting' it from e.g. a factory method etc. Meh. But still. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

From [.NET and COM: The Complete Interoperability Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232170X):

When an instance of a COM object is returned to you, via a method's return type or a by-reference parameter, and the CLR can't determine the type, you'll get the generic System.__ComObject type because COM objects are always passed/returned as interface pointers.

You might try changing the return type using `Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType` as in the example below:

```
MyType newObject = (MyType)Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType(oldObject, typeof(MyType))
```

Then you can look at newObject in your watch window and it should have the expected properties.

If the call fails, it will throw an InvalidCastException.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the immediate window to manually query the properties of the COM object.  The downside is that I don't think you get intellisense so you have to know exactly what you want to inspect.

Comment: Yeah it works 'manually'.. but I am looking for a way to display the whole object properly