# How to debug applications using COM interfaces?

Tags: c#, com, debugging, watch, catia

I'm building an application using `C#` which will use CATIA COM modules. When I import the COM inside my `C#` project, I think that `Visual C# Express` generates the Interop automagically for me.

All of this works correctly. However, when I try to debug the application and use watches during runtime, every object is a `System.__ComObject` and I cannot get their "real" value.

Is there a way to tell the debugger the types of my `COM` objects?

The goal is to get more familiar with this new API I don't know really well. Sometimes it's rather hard to guess the correct types for everything since the interface hierarchy is quite deep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't post a code example where you have a problem. Mostly it's depend on **how you create or cast an object** which you want to see in Debugger (create an instance of the object with `new` is always better, if it is possible of course). You should search for information about Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW). This is "the guy" who can not understand what you want.

By the way if you can use Visual Studio 2010 your life can be easier (see [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/habibh/debugging-a-com-object-runtime-callable-wrapper-with-visual-studio-2010)).

Two links can help you to solve the problem if you use

http://dotnetdebug.net/category/com-interop/

http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/e6532ba4-d769-48a6-8bc4-8592352b9bf4.htm

[Inspecting an instance of a COM / Interop class properly in VS.Net's debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306262/inspecting-an-instance-of-a-com-interop-class-properly-in-vs-nets-debugger)

http://dotnetdebug.net/2005/09/10/runtime-callable-wrapper-internals-and-common-pitfalls/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check this out monday while I get paid to do so =)

Comment: And it is better you give a simple overview once you get it done, for the convenience of other audience, Eric:)

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio if you open tools >> Options and then debugging >> General make sure the option "Use managed compatibility mode" it checked on. This should show com objects as their proper types in the debugger.

Comment: "The managed compatibility mode option is deprecated and will be removed in future versions of Visual Studio."